# Python's struct.calcsize to PHP

Tags: php, python, function, python-3.x, struct

Is there any particular (built in or custom) way or function in PHP that is equivalent to this python code:

```
struct.calcsize(fmt)
```

Comment: [unpack](http://php.net/unpack) is the closest thing you can find in php.

Comment: Yeah. I actually have that one to parse my binary file. However, I need to specify the size explicitly in my fread call. fread($resource, $size);

Comment: [filesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) ?